# String as link to directory

Tags: python, path, directory

Something I do not understand is happening:

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

v = "/Desktop/data/s/g/pg.shp"
r = "/Desktop/data/raw/tem/g01.asc"

stats = zonal_stats(v, r)
```

Work perfectly. However, I want to iterate through the folder `tem` it does not.

```
pathToRasterFolder = "/Desktop/data/raw/tem/"

for files in os.listdir(pathToRasterFolder):
    if files.endswith(".asc"):
        zonalStats = ("/Desktop/data/s/g/pg.shp", pathToRasterFolder + files)
        print zonalStats
```

That does not work. My result is:

```
> ("/Desktop/data/s/g/pg.shp", "/Desktop/data/raw/tem/g01.asc")
```

Why doesnt it accept the path to the directory with the files?

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: In the first example, you are calling the `zonal_stats` function. Perhaps you meant to call the function in the second example rather than creating a tuple: `zonalStats = zonal_stats("/Desktop/data/s/g/pg.shp", pathToRasterFolder + files)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, `zonal_stats` is a function; in the second, you assign it a tuple.

Comment: well, that happens when you stare to long on your code. thanks!